# Make box on right and show content fom right to left

Tags: html, css, transition

It's hard to explain what I want to do.

On my codepen example I have a standard box (normal size `240px`), when I click plus it shows the whole content from left to right (to `800px`).

What I want to achieve is to place content to left, box to right (this box which has `240px`, only the box should be visible before click minus) and when I click plus show the content from right to left. (reverse is what I have now).

```
`https://codepen.io/bobobob22/pen/OxOBPg`
```

Comment: Please don't circumvent the rules by placing the url to a codepen in code blocks like that.  The rules exist for a reason, you should post some code in
 the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options, which is better depends on the rest of your layout.  First, you could simply float it to the right,

```
.awwards-square {
    Float: right;
}
```

Alternatively, you could position it absolutely,

```
.awwards-square {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```